# Efficient way of counting number of records per day within date range in Rails without requiring one query per day

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

Rails app using `fullcalendar.js` to generate a reservation calendar that shows, on each day, the count of *check-ins*, *check-outs* and **in progress** `reservations` **for each date**.

This is a sample outcome:

[image]

Using SQL I'm able to group reservations by `check-in` and `check-out` and easily generate the JSON with the count for each day (since these two dates - check in and check-out - are actual columns in the database). All it takes are 2 queries (one for check-ins, another one for check-outs).

But I don't know how to handle the `in progress` counts, since the dates are not in the database, being the `void` between the `check_in` and `check_out` dates.

My current solution (the only one I could think of) requires looping over each `day` of the calendar and issuing a SQL count for the reservations whose `check_in < day AND check_out > day`, but that takes a LOT of SQL queries (one for each day in the calendar view). This is the current *working* code:

```
# Start_date and end_date are provided by fullcallendar.js params
start_date, end_date = Date.parse(start_date_string), Date.parse(end_date_string)

# In progress
last_in_progress_event = nil

array = []

(start_date..end_date).each do |day|

  count = current_user.reservations.where("DATE(check_in) < :date AND DATE(check_out) > :date", date: day).size

  if count > 0
    # If the count > 0, there's an active reservation on this day. If the
    # count changed when compared to the previous day, we create a new event
    # on fullcalendar (to change the `title` of the event with the new count).
    # If the count remained the same as the previous event, we can just update
    # it's end date to the current date being analyzed so se get a nice UI
    # (continuous event while the count doesn't change instead of one event
    # per day)

    if last_in_progress_event && last_in_progress_event[:count] == count
      # Day + 1 is required due to fullcalendar.js cutting the event short one day
      last_in_progress_event[:end] = (day + 1)
    else
      last_in_progress_event = {
        title: "#{count} in progress",
        start: day,
        end: (day + 1),
        allDay: true,
        className: 'bgm-lightblue',
        count: count
      }

      array.push(last_in_progress_event)
    end

  end # if count > 0

end

array
```

Would there be a way of building this hash of `{day: in_progress_count}` without 30+ queries per month?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for, but it seems a BETWEEN clause is more than enough for getting what you desired. I don't understand what do you mean by iterating thou. It may not be as hard as you think. Could you post a sample records and the desired output?

Comment: @Learning I added a sample image to help visualization. Right now I'm iterating in all visible days of the calendar (in the example image, it goes from day 30 of previous month to 9 of next month) and issuing a count on each single day.

Comment: Can you also post the current code that you have? But since you need to count the in progress for each day you need to create a stored procedure using prepared statement  and prepared the days for the entire month and join it to your table and issue a count.

Comment: @Learning updated with existing code.

Comment: Forget about the ruby stuff for now, and instead see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Could you try something like this one?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `GetInprogressCount`(m_DateFrom DATE,
                                       m_DateTo DATE)
BEGIN

    DECLARE m_Counter INTEGER;
    DECLARE m_SQLDates LONGTEXT;
    DECLARE m_CheckDate DATE;
    SET m_Counter = 0;
    SET m_SQLDates = '';

    CreateDates: LOOP
      SET m_CheckDate = DATE_ADD(m_DateFrom, INTERVAL m_Counter DAY);
      SET m_SQLDates = CONCAT(m_SQLDates, IF(Trim(m_SQLDates) <> "", " UNION ALL ",""),"(SELECT '", m_CheckDate,
                              "' AS CheckDate )");
      SET m_Counter = m_Counter + 1;
      IF m_Counter < DATEDIFF(m_DateTo, m_DateFrom)+1 THEN
          ITERATE CreateDates;
      ELSE
          LEAVE CreateDates;
      END IF;

    END LOOP CreateDates;
    SET @m_SQLInProgress = CONCAT("SELECT v.CheckDate, Count(*) InProgressCount FROM (",m_SQLDates,") v ",
                                  "LEFT JOIN yourtable t ON t.check_in < v.CheckDate AND ",
                                  "t.check_out > v.CheckDate GROUP BY v.CheckDate"); 

    PREPARE m_SQLDates FROM @m_SQLInProgress;
    EXECUTE m_SQLDates;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE m_SQLDates;
END
```

Modify the code based on your requirements. Play with it until you get your desired output.

Comment: I appreciate the help - really do - but I wouldn't know how to use that in a Rails ActiveRecord query.

Comment: Hmm I thought you wanted to have a SQL query that would count the In Progress daily instead of a loop. You also tagged SQL and the code above will only work on MYSQL.I didn't mean to miss lead you. How are you  using your current query to your ActiveRecord? Like your Count for check in and Check out date?